# pushing from one --bare repo to another --bare repo on same server

Tags: git

I have a remote repo on a server that I push to for staging purposes.  I then have a post-receive to push that to the file directory where http://stage.xxxx.com files live on.

Now that I have everything on my staging repo and it's presumed to be bug free, how do I push it from my staging repo to my live repo on the same server?

I would prefer to not have to push my local code directly to the production git repo because I'm shall we say not the best at keeping track of that kind of stuff.  Would I have to login directly to the server and do a push from there to the live repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to log in directly to the server, and that solution seems a little bit overcomplicated, because you can just do something like this:

```
git fetch --all
git push livesite staging/master:master
```

This will push the state of **staging/master** to **livesite/master** and you do not have to keep track of anything.

Comment: Since I'm the only person working on this repo at this time, I only have to do the git fetch --all once, correct?  Other than that, it works perfectly and is correct! Thanks!

Comment: If your local repo is the only one that pushes to these remotes (and don’t run git commands in these repos on the server), you should always have the current state of these repos. So you should **never** have to run `git fetch` at all. I added that because my `git push` command will push to the livesite whatever your client thinks is currently on the staging site – not what’s actually on the staging site. `git fetch` makes sure these are the same things. If your client is already up to date, `git fetch` is indeed not needed.